# Is it possible to rotate an artboard 45 degrees?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

[image]

Is it possible to rotate this so that the hole indicated on the top left is at the top center?  I want to be lined up corner to corner under the hole. If I can't rotate the artboard what is another way I would be able to do this...thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

No. You can not rotate Illustrator artboards.

You would need to create an artboard the size of the diagonal, then center the artwork within that.

[image]

You can also:

- Select All
- Rotate 45°
- choose `Object > Artboards > Fit to Selected Art`

For print reproduction services this is *entirely* unnecessary. You leave the artwork as you have it. This is really only needed for some sort of visual representation of a final print piece or a mock up.